# filter path based on decorating node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following graph

```
[a1:A]->[b1:B]->[c1:C]->[d1:D]

[a2:A]->[b2:B]->[c2:C]->[d2:D]
                  ^
                  |
                  [x1:X]
```

If I use the query

```
match p=((:A)-[*]->(:D))
```

then it returns both path above, but I want to filter the second path out because there is a label X node pointing to node C. What is the query to use that returns only the path that does not contain nodes that are decorated by node label X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this

```
MATCH p=((:A)-[*]->(:D))
WHERE NONE(node IN nodes(p) WHERE EXISTS((node)<--(:X))  )
RETURN p
```